# Find the minimum values of $a^3$ and $b^3$ from the following given cubic function.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Today after teaching AM,GM,HM relations my teacher proposed this question.
*It isn't a HW though, since we don't have to tell that we solved the question and submit a solution.*

**Question**

> Given that $a,b$ are two positive real numbers.
>   If $$f(x)=2x^3+ax^2+bx+4=0$$
>   Find the minimum values of $a^3$ and $b^3$.

Well I have progressed a bit.
Applying $AM\ge GM${taking all the terms in $f(x)$ positive}
We get $8x^6ab\le0$ which is impossible since $x$ can't be $0$ and $a,b$ are positive.
So we have a conclusion that roots of $f(x)$ are negative.
Now putting $x=-X$ where $X$ is positive real number, we get
$2X^3+bX=aX^2+4$

This is all useful I got. Using AM,GM on the both the sides one by one yields two inequalities of no use.
Thanks for any solution or hint in advance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: This seems like a trick question. $x$ is not defined, so the question seems to allow any $x$. Now for a real cubic there must be at least one real root, so any $a,b$ would suffice. Since the cube function is unbounded, so are $a^3$ and $b^3$ then, both ways. What is wrong?

Comment: Maybe it means that this equation has three real roots?

Comment: @Shaun-Is it OK now?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg- It can have 3 negative roots or 1. But I'm certain that all of them are negative.

Comment: Maybe the given equation is $2x^3-ax^2+bx-4=0$ and this equation has three real roots? Otherwise, there is a problem in the formulation.

Comment: @Michael Won't both the equations have same roots except for the sign i.e. of opposite signs. But how they will have 3 roots?

Comment: It should be given, otherwise, I think your problem is not correct. The minimum value of a positive number does not exist,

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg- What if there is one root which gives an equation a,b? From which we will find minimum value of a,b since both of them are positive.

Comment: If there is one real root only, so for example, the minimal value of $a^3$ does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch.

Assume $a, b \geq 0$. Let the roots be denoted $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

Using Vieta's formula we find
\begin{align}
x_1+x_2+x_3 &=  -\frac{a}{2} \\
x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 +x_3 x_1&= \frac{b}{2} \\
x1 x_2 x_3 &= -2
\end{align}
The last inequality implies that 
$$2 = (-x_1)(-x_2)(-x_3) = |x_1||x_2||x_3|$$

Applying AM-GM, then
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{6} &= -\frac{1}{3}(x_1+x_2+x_3) \\
&\geq ((-x_1)(-x_2)(-x_3))^{1/3} \\
&= \ldots
\end{align}

Also, 
\begin{align}
\frac{b}{6} &= \frac{1}{3}(x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 +x_3 x_1)\\
&\geq (x_1 x_2 x_1 x_3 x_2 x_3)^{1/3}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Then, once you have found $a, b$ above the minimums will follow.

Comment: @Kevin- Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Kevin Your both inequalities they are wrong. Try $x_1=-1$, $x_2=i$ and $x_3=-i$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg- Product of roots would be -1 but it should be -2 according to question.

Comment: @Love Invariants Take $x_1=-2$. It does not change. The solution of Kevin is total wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg- Idk, but the same solution was given in a book for 2 same type of questions. for $x_1=-2$ ,$b=2$, $a=4$. So what now, both would be greater than the values mentioned in the solution.

Comment: @Love Invariants Take, for example,  the equation $2x^3+0.00000001x^2+0.000000001x+4=0$. Maybe now do you see that the minimal value of $a^3$ does not exist?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg- Does your equation have a real root? f(x)=0 for some real x.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value of a positive number does not exist, which says that a minimal value of $a^3$ does not exist and a minimum value of $b^3$ does not exist.

Comment: @ Michael - Why though?

Comment: @Love Invariants Do you ask why does not exist a minimal positive number? By the way, the Kevin's solution is total wrong.

Comment: If $a=b=0$, we have a perfectly valid solution when $x=\sqrt[3]{-2}$.  Clearly $a,b$ can be arbitrarily close to $0$ and still positive, due to continuity of roots wrt coefficients, there will still be a valid real root in a nbd of $\sqrt[3]{-2}$.  So there is no minimum. Micheal is correct.